# The physical interpretation of the trip inside Kerr (black hole) spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, kerr-metric, white-holes

Consider then the Kerr metric$[1]$:

$$ds^{2} = -\Bigg(1-\frac{2Mr}{\rho^2}\Bigg)dt^2 - \frac{2Marsin^2(\theta)}{\rho^2}[dt d\phi+d\phi dt] +$$
$$+\frac{\rho^2}{\Delta}dr^2+\rho^2d\theta^2+ \frac{sin^2(\theta)}{\rho^2}\Big[(r^2+a^2)^2 - a^2\Delta sin^2(\theta) \Big]d\phi^2 \tag{1}$$

Where $\Delta$ and $\rho$ are:

$$\Delta (r) = r^2-2GMr+a^2$$
$$\rho^2 (r,\theta) = r^2+a^2cos^2(\theta)$$

And $a$ are the quantity which ensambles the angular momentum parameter of the black hole.

$$a = \frac{J}{M}$$

So, this solution introduce a more complex Penrose Diagram, which is $[2]$:

[image]

Now, the $I$ region is where we "departed", towards the Black Hole interior $II$. In this travel, $I \to II$, we must to cross the exterior event horizon $r=r_{+}$.

Then in principle is possible to travel throughout the region $III$ and avoid the singularity $r=0$. For this trip, then we must to cross the inner event horizon $r=r_{-}$. The trip, so far is then:

[image]

Here comes my doubt. To exit the Kerr black hole to the region $I$ (the above $I$) we must to cross problematic surfaces concerning, in my opinion, the physical interpretation. I mean,

[image]

First one is (again) the $r=r_{-}$ (Orange) and then the other event horizon $r=r_{+}$ (Green) , i.e. :

[image]

Well, concerning the (Orange) inner horzion, I can avoid in this question and accept that this is a wormhole throat and then is possible to be crossed (even still isn't a proper traversable wormhole solution $[3]$). But I'm struggling to understand the (green) event horizon concerning the intuitive idea of "What I would see and Where I would land". I mean, due to the knowledge of Penrose diagrams, after you cross the green horizon you are in the $i^{-}$ so you are in the past infinity of particles of Universe $I$(ABOVE).

So my doubt is: we know for sure that the solution is for ONE object. So, the universe $I$(ABOVE) must to be the same as the one we have departed from ($I$ our present universe). Knowing that, after your travel through the Kerr black hole, would you appear in the past infinity of $I$ universe?

$$* * *$$

$[1]$ CARROLL.S; Spacetime and Geometry. 1.ed. Pearson: Chicago,2003.

$[2]$ HAWKING.S,ELLIS.G.; Large-scale structure of Space-time.

$[3]$ MICHAEL.S, MORRIS and THORNE.K.S.; Wormholes in spacetime and their use for interstellar travel: a tool for teaching general relativty,Am.J.Phys,v.56,n.5,p.395,1988.